# Removing default textbox border animation in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a global style for all my textboxes like so:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>                
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007acc"/>        
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GhostWhite"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#49494e"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
</Style>
```

When I hover over a textbox with a mouse, its border color will correctly snap to a red color for couple of instants but then the default animation takes over and changes it into the default textbox bluish border color.

How can I disable, or overwrite this animation without having to redefine the entire textbox template? I just want the border color to stay red, while the mouse cursor is hovering over the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to your problem would be to change `Template` of `TextBox`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
               <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
            </Border>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007acc"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GhostWhite"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#49494e"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
   <Setter Property="Width" Value="250"/>
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known issue with property precedence. Basically your local property setter for the border brush is clashing with your trigger. This [Msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) explains it more fully but essentially if you remove

```
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007acc"/>
```

your trigger should work correctly

Comment: If i remove that then i will lose the color for my border when it's not being hovered over, and if i try to remedy this by  moving the setter into < Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"> then it does exactly what it did before with the animation.